# Requesting flair for non-existing user goes wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

When I requested a user's flair page for a non-existing user I got a dialog that said
'Framing not allowed, click OK to continue':
[image]

After clicking 'OK' (the only option) my original page is replaced by a (meta.)stackoverflow 'page not found' page.

Try setting up a page with the following iframe content to reproduce:

```
<iframe src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/500.html?theme=clean" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
    frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" width="210px" height="60px"></iframe>
```

This will try to load the flair page for the non-existing meta user 500.

Currently it is quit hard to load a page with such content.
I try to setup a page where a forum member can give his stackoverflow user number, and show the flair page for that given user by accessing the correct iframe.

Could this be fixed in any way?
What I would like to see is a flair iframe, with a 'User not found' or something similar. Or just a plain 404 HTTP error.

Comment: There's your problem: your browser appears to be using some crazy, non-English language.

Comment: Well the issue is that Stackoverflow sends a message that forces the web browser to dump the iframe and replace the whole page with a page not found.
Ton

Comment: Making the localization of the browser the source of the bug is quite ignorant and pity.

Ton

Comment: He was \*trying\* to make a joke.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the joke effort, if it was accompanied by something valuable (no harm done though).

Comment: time to get out your frame buster buster

Comment: We'll return a plain text 404 instead of including a master page with a frame buster when a user isn't found.

Comment: Geoff could you respond with an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We'll return a plain text 404 instead of including a master page with a frame buster when a user isn't found. Geoff Dalgas

Yes it is fixed, thanks!

Ton